# Pass parameter with Heroku dataclips json url

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres

Issue-1 
select statement - "Select field1,field2 from table1 " 
Requirement -This statement return 10 rows but i need only rows which have value 300 on field1. but this value 300 get changed time to time.Therefor i can not put where condition and mention value 300.

Is there a way to pass parameter with Json url and filter only the required row base on the value on parameter?

Regards

Chamika Perera